# Android injecting class return null

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm using JobQueue library and i can successful inject some class such as GithubService to that for example:

```
public interface GithubService {
    @GET("repositories")
    Call<List<GithubRepo>> getAllRepositories();
}
```

now i'm trying to inject other class as `RxBus`

```
public interface Bus {

    void register(@NonNull Object observer);

    <T> CustomSubscriber<T> obtainSubscriber(@NonNull Class<T> eventClass, @NonNull Consumer<T> receiver);

    <T> void registerSubscriber(@NonNull Object observer, @NonNull CustomSubscriber<T> subscriber);

    void unregister(@NonNull Object observer);

    void post(@NonNull Object event);

}
```

into job file, but i get null

**job class:**

```
public class GetLatestRepositories extends Job implements JobManagerInjectable {
    @Inject
    transient GithubService githubService;

    @Inject
    transient Bus eventBus;

    private Call<List<GithubRepo>> repositoryCall;

    public GetLatestRepositories() {
        super(new Params(JobPriority.MID).requireNetwork().persist());
        eventBus.register(this); /* IS NULL*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdded() {
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void inject(ApplicationComponent component) {
        component.inject(this);
    }
}
```

**ApplicationComponent**

```
@ActivitiesScope
@Component(dependencies = GithubApplicationComponent.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(ActivityRegister activityRegister);

    void inject(ActivityStartUpApplication activityStartUpApplication);

    void inject(GetLatestRepositories getLatestRepositories);
}
```

**GithubApplicationComponent**

```
@AlachiqApplicationScope
@Component(
        modules = {
                UserInformationModule.class,
                NetworkServiceModule.class,
                PicassoModule.class,
                JobManagerModule.class,
                RxModule.class,
                ActivityModule.class
        }
)
public interface GithubApplicationComponent {
    Picasso getPicasso();
    GithubService getGithubService();
    JobManager getJobManager();
    Bus getBus();
}
```

**RxModule**

```
@Module
public class RxModule {
    @Provides
    @AlachiqApplicationScope
    public Bus getBus() {
        return new RxBus();
    }
}
```

[RxBux files](https://github.com/Anadea/RxBus/tree/master/rxbus/src/main/java/com/anadeainc/rxbus)

Comment: Which module `@Provides` `Bus` instance? Share the code of that module.

Comment: @azizbekian my post updated, i added to end of my post

Comment: Where is `RxBus` class?

Comment: @azizbekian in my Library folder into project

Comment: Post that class also.

Comment: @azizbekian RxBus Files: https://github.com/Anadea/RxBus/tree/master/rxbus/src/main/java/com/anadeainc/rxbus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141814/discussion-between-tux-world-and-azizbekian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `RxModule` instead of:

```
return new RxBus();
```

Do:

```
return BusProvider.getInstance();
```

Comment: Thank you very much